# Work from home, remote monitoring software, vpn, privacy

Tags: appsec, vpn, hardware, corporate-policy

So I work for a company where I make and receive phone calls and connect to remote servers and workstations.  I work from home, use a company laptop and connect to the company's network via software VPN . The hardware setup is a laptop, monitor, Plantronics box, phone line, cable modem/router w/ RJ11 & RJ45 ports, cat 6 cabling.

The company can remotely monitor my work laptop via software.  They have the ability to capture video and images on the screen of the laptop.

There are periods of significant downtime during which I'd like to work on personal stuff on my personal laptop. For a variety of reasons, I need to use only one monitor and switch video between the two laptops.

So I bought an IOGEAR 2 port USB KVM switch model GCS632U. Also bought a Kinesis Freestlye 2 keyboard and couple wifi/BT dongles.  The IOGEAR KVM can switch between between laptops using a hotkey, no software required.

My intention is to set up a hardware solution so my activity on my personal laptop cannot be monitored by the company from the work laptop. My question is, is it possible for the company to monitor or view my personal laptop video output or screen from the work laptop if I am using the KVM hardware setup that I described?  Is the hardware setup adequate?  Is there a more effective or efficient way to accomplish my objective? Thanks.

Comment: screen monitoring software monitors the video card, not the screen

Comment: You could: buy a hard drive and boot from it (get windows or whatever system you are using in it) and do personal stuff from there, you could boot in safemode with wifi from your laptop (that way only the needed software is executed, not your company software)

Answer (score 1):

The screen and KVM are irrelevant. The software is on your work computer. That computer and it's output will be monitored. If you switch to the other laptop, the monitoring will still record the old one's screen. There is no actual problem in your case.